# Save specific columns to new xlsx file with vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, xlsx

I have a a xlsx file with lots of columns and rows. I need to select sepcific columns to generate a new xlsx file.
My code is:

```
Public Sub xlsToCsv()    
Dim WorkingDir
WorkingDir = "C:\test.xlsx"

Dim fso, FileName, SaveName, myFile
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFile = fso.GetFile(WorkingDir)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(myFile)

With objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range("D87", .Range("D87").End(-4121)).Copy
        objWorkbook.Sheets.Add().paste
        .Range("E87", .Range("E87").End(-4121)).Copy
End With

dim sheet: set sheet =  objWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
sheet.paste
objWorkbook.SaveAs("E:\test.csv"), 23
objWorkbook.Saved = true
objWorkbook.Close

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
End Sub
call xlsToCsv()
```

But this doesn't copy the whole column. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you tell us what does it do when you say it doesn't copy the whole column ?

Comment: the copy property of the worbooks object cannot be matched. error in line 14 (set objworkbook = objecel.workbooks.open(myfile))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your error but here are a few pointers.

You shouldn't use parentheses calling a sub and are also trying to save it as a different file format: `objWorkbook.SaveAs("C:\test.xls")`.

Here only the last copy range is being copied:

```
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D8").EntireColumn.Copy
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A8").EntireColumn.Copy
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F8").EntireColumn.Copy
```

A better way is to use `Columns` and `.Copy Destination` to copy the data.

```
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns("D").Copy sheet.Columns("A")
```

---

```
Const WorkingDir = "C:\"
Const xlCSVMSDOS = 24
Dim fso, SaveName, myFile
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, wsSource, wsTarget

myFile = "test.xlsx"
SaveName =WorkingDir & "test.csv"

With CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    If Not .FileExists(WorkingDir & myFile) Then
        MsgBox "File not found:" & vbCrLf & WorkingDir & myFile, vbInformation, "Script Cancelled"
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End With

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WorkingDir & myFile)
Set wsSource = objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
set wsTarget =  objWorkbook.Sheets.Add()

wsSource.Columns("D").Copy wsTarget.Columns("A")
wsSource.Columns("A").Copy wsTarget.Columns("B")
wsSource.Columns("F").Copy wsTarget.Columns("C")


objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName, xlCSVMSDOS
objWorkbook.Close False
```

---

Here is how you can copy the data from a column starting at a specific row.

```
Const xlUp = -4162
With wsSource
    .Range("D87", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy wsTarget.Range("A1")
    .Range("A87", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy wsTarget.Range("B1")
    .Range("F87", .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy wsTarget.Range("C1")
End With
```

Comment: thank you for your enhancements. But there is an error in line 14 (set objworkbook = objexcel.workbooks.open(myfile), code: 800A03EC , the open property of the woorkbooks object cant be assigned.

Comment: The file must not exists.  I updated my code. You should downlaod [VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/default.asp?adwords=2&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvOzOBRDGARIsAICjxofmPtjx4fcbksZ1No1C1FXRJgS7etPYxyrxqFz-q18pIcBVCcywGgkaAoiwEALw_wcB).

Comment: the problem was that i didnt add the WorkingDir to the file name in  "Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(myFile)". But it doesnt copy anything now.

Comment: I just tested it.   `objWorkbook.Sheets(1)` was referring to the new sheet because the new sheet is being added before all the other sheets.  I updated my answer.

Comment: so I nearly got everything I need. How can I copy the column at "D87" not ad "D1"?